# Stop a spring batch job based on the STATUS

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have spring batch job configured in my JAVA application, the application runs in a cluster. Hence the same job gets executed twice, which I don't want.

So I want to configure a step within the job which will check if CREATE_DATE is present for that day in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table and will continue or fail over.

How can this be configured within a spring batch step ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html).
From Javadoc:

> Interface allowing for programmatic access to the decision on what the
>   status of a flow should be. For example, if some condition that's
>   stored in the database indicates that the job should stop for a manual
>   check, a decider implementation could check that value to determine
>   the status of the flow